# Puntuación de un enunciado

Tags: puntuación

¡Hola! Una amiga lleva la página de cierta asociación en Instagram y a la hora de redactar una pequeña descripción acerca de lo que hace dicha asociación tuvo varias dudas acerca de la puntuación. El texto aquí.

> En esta asociación somos creyentes de que toda persona merece una vida digna. Al igual que el hambre, la menstruación debe ser transmitida y considerada como un tema prioritario a través de una cultura de naturalidad, positividad y concientización para todo el país. Si deseas conocer más del tema, tenemos un IGTV al respecto o puedes consultar a diferentes organizaciones que se enfocan en la menstruación digna en esta liga.

Particularmente, las dudas surgen en si es correcto haber escrito «En esta asociación somos creyentes de que toda persona...» o en su lugar debería ser «En esta asociación, somos creyentes de que toda persona...» así como también «Si deseas conocer más del tema, tenemos un IGTV...» contra «Si deseas conocer más del tema tenemos un IGTV...» y, en general, con las comas colocadas a lo largo del texto.

Agradeceré muchísimo sus comentarios y su ayuda.

Comment: Podrás encontrar en esta página toda la información relativa al uso de la coma: https://www.rae.es/dpd/coma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según [el DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/coma), se escribe coma (entre muchos otros casos)

> 1.2.10 a) [e]n las oraciones simples, cuando los complementos circunstanciales preceden al verbo, salvo que sean muy cortos: *En aquellos calurosos días de principios del verano pasado, la convivencia era idílica* (pero *En casa no puedo estudiar*).

Por tanto, "En esta asociación" iría seguido de coma solo si no lo consideramos "muy corto". Hay cierta libertad en la interpretación de "muy corto". Yo sí lo consideraría "muy corto" y **no pondría la coma**, también porque tiene una función importante dentro de la oración (indica quién es el sujeto omitido del siguiente verbo).

También se escribe coma

> [e]n las oraciones compuestas, cuando la subordinada adverbial precede a la principal: *Si vas a llegar tarde, no dejes de avisarme; Aunque no lo creas, es verdad; Antes de entrar, dejen salir; Dicho esto, el diputado bajó del estrado*. También en estos casos, si la subordinada es muy breve, puede prescindirse de la coma: *Si lo sé no vengo*.

Por tanto, "Si deseas conocer más del tema" **debe ir seguido de coma**.